# Set Font Color, Font Face and Font Size in PHPExcel

Tags: php, class, phpexcel

I'm working in PHPExcel. I'm beginner.When I'm using following code and its working fine.

```
$phpExcel = new PHPExcel();

$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getFont()->setBold(true)
                                ->setName('Verdana')
                                ->setSize(10)
                                ->getColor()->setRGB('6F6F6F');
```

But when I'm using following code and not getting expected result as above.

```
$phpFont = new PHPExcel_Style_Font();
$phpFont->setBold(true);
$phpFont->setName('Verdana');
$phpFont->setSize(15);

$phpColor = new PHPExcel_Style_Color();
$phpColor->setRGB('FF0000');  

$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->setFont( $phpFont );
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setColor( $phpColor );
```

Please help me what am I doing wrong in above code.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I recommend you start reading [the documentation](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/documentation) (4.6.18. Formatting cells). When applying a lot of formatting it's better to use `applyFromArray()` According to the documentation this method is also suppose to be faster when you're setting many style properties. There's an annex where you can find all the possible keys for this function.

This will work for you:

```
$phpExcel = new PHPExcel();

$styleArray = array(
    'font'  => array(
        'bold'  => true,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000'),
        'size'  => 15,
        'name'  => 'Verdana'
    ));

$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue('Some text');
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

To apply font style to complete excel document:

```
 $styleArray = array(
   'font'  => array(
        'bold'  => true,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000'),
        'size'  => 15,
        'name'  => 'Verdana'
    ));      
 $phpExcel->getDefaultStyle()
    ->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

Comment: I've trawled the documentation and can't find a list of styling options for the cells anywhere. Any idea where one would get those?

Comment: Inside the document [PHPExcel developer documentation](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/119187) there is an **Appendix A: Valid array keys for style `applyFromArray()`** where you find all the keys. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Regarding the speed increase using an array:
"This alternative method using arrays should be faster in terms of execution whenever you are setting more than one style property. But the difference may barely be measurable unless you have many different styles in your workbook."

Comment: +1 for mentioning the appendix. This won't win an award for best organized documentation but then again, at least it's a lot of good documentation. More than what I give to my projects... :(

Comment: We need to use setcolor() method and not the apply from array is there any way to do this.

Comment: Note PHPExcel is no longer maintained.  See the answer below for phpspreadsheet.

Answer (score 6):

in other  way , you can use :

```
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('A1')
            ->getFont()
            ->getColor()
            ->setRGB ('EEEEEE')  ;
```

Answer (score 3):

PHPExcel is no longer maintained and replaced by phpspreadsheet.

First read the documentation and use applyFromArray() for applying style and read the documentation of phpspreadsheet:

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$styleArray = [
        'font' => [
            'bold'  =>  true,
            'size'  =>  14,
            'name'  =>  'Arial'
        ],
        'alignment' => [
            'horizontal' => Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
            'vertical' => Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER
        ],
        'borders' => [
            'allBorders' => [
                'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_THIN,
                'color' => ['rgb' => '000000']
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $sheet->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

The documentation can be found [Here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/)

Answer (score 0):

You can using **applyFromArray** function or functions of class **PHPExcel_Style_Font** to setting font style.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("F1:G1")->applyFromArray(array(
    "font"  => array(
        "bold"  => true,
        "color" => array("rgb" => "FF0000"),
        "size"  => 16,
        "name"  => "Arial Black"
    )
));
```

OR

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("F1:G1")->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("F1:G1")->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB("FF0000");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("F1:G1")->getFont()->setSize(16);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("F1:G1")->getFont()->setName("Arial Black");
```