# php to xls not the same like php output & xls output (different)

Tags: php, html

I'm confused about this script php converter:

```
  <?php header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");  
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xls");  ?>
```

and after convert to test.xls

[image]

I wanna make like this, with color and same like output export.php

[image]

with color ,border ,and right placement.

Answer (score 0):

can you please used this library which help you set all thing which you want:

[phpexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

[Feature List](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Features&referringTitle=Documents)

also take reference of this [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317301/set-font-color-font-face-and-font-size-in-phpexcel)