# Phpexcel - how to set the font format of a cell value

Tags: php, wordpress, phpexcel

I am using phpexcel library. but when I want to set the font color, and different style for a cell value then when I export my file then those changes not applied there.
my code is below

```
<?php 
    require_once (SPEE_PLUGIN_DIRS . "/Classes/PHPExcel.php");

    require_once (SPEE_PLUGIN_DIRS . "/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $styleArray = array(
                       'font'  => array(
                       'bold'  => true,
                       'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000'),
                       'size'  => 15,
                       'name'  => 'Verdana'
                       ));                                       

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:H1');

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A2:H2');

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A3:H3');

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()->getStyle('E1')->applyFromArray(array("font" => array( "bold" => true))); // font not set bold.

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', 'my data');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A7')->setValue('CNIC No');  

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A7')->applyFromArray($styleArray); // this style array not work on 'A7'

?>
```

Comment: have you checked following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17619725/1578908

Comment: I have read it, and follow but doesn't get any response in my question. as the issue is still there.

Comment: your code is working at my end, i am not able to open pastebin as it is blocked, pls try alternative way to send code

Comment: try http://phpfiddle.org/ to test and share code

Comment: tryto save with different filename, cell location, cell text etc.

Comment: can you open this file http://hastebin.com/ipepoqipib.coffee . I have tried phpfiddle but that is not responding at my side.

Comment: You can not format csv file OK, for formatted text you will have to write file as xls

Comment: this is only the problem other wise your code is ok, without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom after ob_start(); replace all with the following code

```
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always  modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Comment: I have tried this code, but also not working. I mean when export the file then the text is just normal, and the formating property are not applied there.

Comment: have you tried this method of individual formating $this->workbook->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2')->getFont()->setBold(true);

Comment: here is my excel file link http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=64215884424729145006

Comment: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A7')->getFont()->setBold(true); this is not working also

Comment: replace after the third line from bottom and change the cell address A2 to E1

Comment: when exactly copy and paste this line then gives this error message.
 Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\wamp

Comment: yes, it will error, $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A7')->getFont()->setBold(true);

Comment: check if file is closed and not opened  on your desktop, it might be caching isue, check by deleting cache, as code here is working on my end

Comment: which version of phpexcel you are using

Comment: my complete code for exporting for now is this http://pastebin.com/yv4H86LU   but still have the same issue

Comment: you can test applying richtext format like shown here https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/454327