# Set different font-color inside 1 cell using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to make the text have different color inside 1 cell using PHPExcel, but i can't find the info about it. Is it possible?

I believe it can be done from the xls, but can it be done using programming, in PHPExcel?

Comment: This is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317301/set-font-color-font-face-and-font-size-in-phpexcel

Comment: but that set color for text inside cell, which make 1 cell color. but i want have more than 1 color inside 1 cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can be done in PHPExcel, using Rich Text objects.

They are described in the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#add-rich-text-to-a-cell) and there are [examples provided](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/05featuredemo.inc.php#L116)

```
$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
$objRichText->createText('This invoice is ');
$objPayable = $objRichText->createTextRun('payable within thirty days after the end of the month');
$objPayable->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPayable->getFont()->setItalic(true);
$objPayable->getFont()->setColor(
    new PHPExcel_Style_Color( PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_DARKGREEN )
);
$objRichText->createText(', unless specified otherwise on the invoice.');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A18')->setValue($objRichText);
```

Comment: I have to add specific color to "This invoice is" text which you have mentioned in createText().. please suggest me the changes