# How to color part of an existing text in PHPExcel using RichText

Tags: php, wordpress, phpexcel, richtext

I've been trying to color part of an existing text in my phpExcel file. After some searching I've learned that I should use RichText to achieve that, and so I did:

```
     if($product_name == '2-Day Cleanse'){
     
     $orderSpc = $formatter->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$row)->getValue();
     $twoday = strstr( $orderSpc, '2');
          
           
      if($twoday){

            $objRichText = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\RichText\RichText();
            $phpColor->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_RED);

            $objRichText->createText($orderSpc); 
            $objCleanse = $objRichText->createTextRun($twoday);
            $objCleanse->getFont()->setColor( new \PHPExcel_Style_Color( PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_DARKGREEN ) );
          

           
            $formatter->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$row, $objRichText);

         }

   }
```

I also tried to declared the color in ARGB and RGB as well:

```
            // $objCleanse->getFont()->setColor(new \PHPExcel_Style_Color())->setARGB('FF0000');
```

I am getting a error that says:

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Font::setColor() must be an instance of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color, instance of PHPExcel_Style_Color given

I have searched for a couple of weeks and had no success, so I decided to ask here.
To summarize my question: I am trying to pick only part of my text (part that says: "2 day cleanse") and I used strstr function to grab that text, but it's not the right approach because once I use createTextRun it created another text on top of the existing text and that's not what I want. I want to grab part of the text and apply a green color to it.

I would appreciate if someone help me with that!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set different font-color inside 1 cell using PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277293/set-different-font-color-inside-1-cell-using-phpexcel)

Comment: The exception is clear. You are using the wrong type. It should be something like `->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_RED);`. What version of PHPExcel are you using?

Comment: No. The link does not work because I am trying to color part of my text, and richText()->CreateTextRun() creates a new text. I want some help in how do I pick part of my text and color it.
I also tried this and I didn't get the error, however the color is still not being applied to my text. 
My version is: PHP Version 7.4.20